# React / Javascript can't find the elements in array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LogIssueScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${apiRoot}log_issue`, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          fields: data.fields
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {this.state.fields ? (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col-md-6 my-3 mx-auto">
              this.state.fields.filter(x => (x.choices != null)).map((item,
              index) => (
              <div className="row align-items-center">
                <div className="col-3">{item.name}</div>
                <div className="col my-3 mx-auto">
                  <Dropdown
                    value={item.name}
                    choices={item.choices}
                    id={item.name}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              ))
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          "LOADING"
        )}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-2 my-3 mx-auto">
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Log Issue"
              className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
              onClick={this.onSubmit}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
{
  this.state.fields
    ? this.state.fields
        .filter(x => x.choices != null)
        .map((item, index) => (
          <Dropdown
            value={item.name}
            choices={item.choices}
            id={item.name}
            onSelect={this.handleDropdownSelect}
          />
        ))
    : "LOADING";
}
```

The result of which, is three copies of `'item' is not defined  no-undef`.

The goal is to take the 'fields' array (of objects) in the state, filter it such that only those elements whose 'choices' key is not null remain, and then map the resulting array to a series of dropdowns. I've tried replacing {item.foo} with a string, to confirm that there was nothing wrong with the `Dropdown` component, and indeed, it works correctly. For some reason, map can't find 'item'. I've also tried dropping the keys (i.e. just item, instead of item.foo), to check if that gave a different error, but it didn't.

Comment: That result you see is a *linting* error, not a JS error (maybe the linter doesn't understand JSX as much as it should?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm sorry if my terminology is off, but it doesn't work!

Comment: The code you've shown should be fine. Perhaps with more context...? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yeah, JSX and/or arrow functions...

Comment: @Alex - What he/she means is that that error isn't coming from JavaScript and almost certainly isn't coming from your transpiler, but rather from some other tool. (It looks like [it's ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, sorry, I'm a bit new to Js/React. The react app is using create-react-app, and is run with npm start. This error is under a big "Failed to compile" error on the page served by the npm start command.

Comment: @Alex - The toolchain create-react-app uses is pretty robust. So I think there's some problem with the code *before* the code you've shown. If you do an MCVE, you'll probably find the error (and if you don't, you'll be able to post that MCVE here -- again, a runnable one with Stack Snippets).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm struggling to get it to not complain about stuff that I don't understand. It seems to have an issue with 'require' in the line:  `super(props)`. Does what I've posted help at all in its current form?

Comment: @Alex - Please have another look at the examples and details in [the page on JSX snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) that I linked to. You can't use `import` (but you don't need to with the scripts shown there), and you need to simulate `fetch` rather than literally using it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are one missing curly pairs (`{}`) in your JSX, where you start to write your `filter` method. If you want to use a Javascript expression in your JSX, then you should use curlies (`{}`) again.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {this.state.fields ? (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col-md-6 my-3 mx-auto">
              // here, curlies again
              {this.state.fields
                .filter(x => x.choices != null)
                .map((item, index) => (
                  <div className="row align-items-center">
                    <div className="col-3">{item.name}</div>
                    <div className="col my-3 mx-auto">
                      <Dropdown
                        value={item.name}
                        choices={item.choices}
                        id={item.name}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          "LOADING"
        )}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-2 my-3 mx-auto">
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Log Issue"
              className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
              onClick={this.onSubmit}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

A mimicking version:

```js
const remoteData = {
  fields: [
    { id: "1", name: "foo", choices: ["a"] },
    { id: "2", name: "bar", choices: ["b"] },
    { id: "3", name: "baz", choices: ["c"] },
  ],
};

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(remoteData)));

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest().then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        fields: data.fields,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {this.state.fields ? (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col-md-6 my-3 mx-auto">
              {this.state.fields
                .filter(x => x.choices != null)
                .map(item => (
                  <div className="row align-items-center" key={item.id}>
                    <div className="col-3">{item.name}</div>
                    <div className="col my-3 mx-auto">
                      <Dropdown
                        value={item.name}
                        choices={item.choices}
                        id={item.name}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          "LOADING"
        )}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-2 my-3 mx-auto">
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Log Issue"
              className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
              onClick={this.onSubmit}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Dropdown = ({ name, id }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{name}</p>
    <p>{id}</p>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Just as I was failing miserably to make a snippet. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I've provided a simple snippet as @T.J. Crowder mentioned in their comments. You can examine it as a future reference.

Comment: Ah, I see where I was going wrong with the snippet. Thank you. The snippet editor was just saying "script error" at an unspecified point, which is why I was struggling to debug it.